# Alter normals to exaggerate ridges and valleys?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, normals

I want my material to emphasize crevices and peaks on the model. Any recessed areas that don't get much light, I want them to get even less. Any that are exposed, I want them to get even more. I can get the basic effect from using Pointiness to darken or lighten color, but I want to use it to affect the normals.

In other words, I want to take the normals of the object and somehow make them more extreme.

It seems that this should be possible by using some form of ramping/curving and maybe pointiness. I have tinkered, but not gotten much of an effect. I can't tell if this is because I just haven't found a good setup, or if I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: I don't think adjusting normals is going to solve your problem. If you run a Pointiness into a Color Ramp and move the sliders in towards the middle, you should get the effect you want. You could even run that into a Brightness/Contrast to make it more dramatic.

Comment: Keep in mind normals don't alter the **actual** shape of the surface, only which direction the surface pretends to be facing. There are no actual recesses to darken with a normal map. To fake these recesses, you generally use an occlusion map instead. (While you can still use an occlusion map with some lighting tricks, they have fallen out of favor in Blender with Cycles, and I have found no easy way to generate them in Cycles.) If you can work back to a bump map, I recommend you try the displacement modifier with the experimental OpenSubDiv support in the subdivision surface modifier instead

Comment: If you want to try using custom normals, Blend4Web includes a Normal Editor. You can install Blend4Web and even if you don't create any web content you can still use the Normal Editor with Cycles. Once installed clicking the Activate button is the same as turning on Auto Smooth in the Mesh context tab. So Auto Smooth must be enabled to use the Normal Editor in Cycles. But yeah, why not give it a try?

Comment: " Any recessed areas that don't get much light, I want them to get even less."  This is almost the textbook definition of an AO pass. An AO pass will enhance the effect of crevices, as they will tend to be darker and filled and grime.  This black an white AO pass can have it's contrast increased or exaggerated using colorramps and is used in the compositor multiplied with your combined render.